# Eclipse Django Plugin

Tags: django, eclipse

Is there an Eclipse plugin to help with Django projects/apps? If there are multiple choices, what is your recommendation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For stuff related to Python, we have a single choice - use pydev + pydev extensions ([here](http://fabioz.com/pydev/)). Regarding front end stuff, I recommend Aptana Studio ([here](http://aptana.com)) (Aptana has recently acquired pydev, by the way).

Answer (score 0):

I also use Aptana Studio, which works allright. But remember: it is only a Python-plugin, not a Django-Plugin, so you won't get anyhelp with django commands (i.e. create app).
I don't have the server running inside eclipse.